# How can I order by date before self joining a table

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

How can I order my results by date_added descending in the whole table before searching for equal_listings in my query down below? Now when I try to order it leaves me hanging.

```
SELECT objects_2.created_at, objects_2.uuid, objects_2.price, objects_2.address, objects_2.square_meters,
    ARRAY(SELECT ROW(created_at, square_meters, uuid, price, address) 
          FROM objects 
          WHERE uuid != objects_2.uuid 
          AND floor = objects_2.floor 
          AND square_meters = objects_2.square_meters
          AND latitude >= (objects_2.latitude - (0.03 * (360 / (cos(objects_2.latitude) * 40075))))
          AND latitude <= (objects_2.latitude + (0.03 * (360 / (cos(objects_2.latitude) * 40075))))
          AND longitude >= (objects_2.longitude - (0.03 * (360 / (cos(objects_2.longitude) * 40075))))
          AND longitude <= (objects_2.longitude + (0.03 * (360 / (cos(objects_2.longitude) * 40075))))
          AND CASE 
                WHEN square_meters IS NOT NULL 
                THEN square_meters = objects_2.square_meters 
              END)
    AS equal_listings 
FROM objects objects_1, objects objects_2
WHERE objects_2.square_meters != 0
ORDER BY objects_2.date_added DESC <--- this leaves me hanging with no response
LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: Use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to gather all of your `object_1` data and then apply the `equal_listings` query to that.

Comment: You mean adding this  `WITH cte_objects_1 AS (SELECT * FROM objects ORDER BY date_added DESC)` at the top and modifying this line `FROM objects objects_1, objects objects_2` to this `FROM cte_objects_1 objects_1, objects objects_2`?

Comment: I don't understand the benefits of ordering the intermediate query result before searching for equal_listings The usual way is to order the final query result except when the intermediate order impacts the downstream queries, but it seems not to be your case. Can you explain please ? Then the joined table objects as objects_1 sounds like useless in your query, is it because you've only shared a simplified version of the real query ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution to my own question.
Correct me if I have done something wrong.

```
SELECT objects_2.date_added, objects_2.updated_at, objects_2.uuid, objects_2.price, objects_2.address, objects_2.square_meters,
    ARRAY(SELECT ROW(date_added, updated_at, created_at, square_meters, uuid, price, address) 
          FROM (select * from objects)objects
          WHERE open = true 
          AND uuid != objects_2.uuid 
          AND floor = objects_2.floor 
          AND latitude >= (objects_2.latitude - (0.03 * (360 / (cos(objects_2.latitude) * 40075))))
          AND latitude <= (objects_2.latitude + (0.03 * (360 / (cos(objects_2.latitude) * 40075))))
          AND longitude >= (objects_2.longitude - (0.03 * (360 / (cos(objects_2.longitude) * 40075))))
          AND longitude <= (objects_2.longitude + (0.03 * (360 / (cos(objects_2.longitude) * 40075))))
          AND CASE 
                WHEN object_type IN ('flat', 'commercial_space') AND objects.square_meters IS NOT NULL THEN square_meters = objects_2.square_meters
              END)
    AS equal_listings
FROM (SELECT * FROM objects ORDER BY date_added DESC) objects_2
WHERE objects_2.square_meters != 0
LIMIT 30
OFFSET 0;
```